# Change the default firewalld zone for podman networks

Tags: networking, rhel, firewalld, podman

Whenever `podman` creates a new network (interface) - by default - it adds it to the *trusted* zone of `firewalld` as described [here](https://firewalld.org/2020/09/policy-objects-filtering-container-and-vm-traffic):

> Podman adds each container to firewalld's `trusted` zone.

You can add these networks to another zone later, e. g. with:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=myzone --change-source=10.88.0.14/32
```

But as the networks will be determined at runtime, it is hard to automate this in an IaC context. So, is there a way to change the default zone of `podman` from *trusted* to something else?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment. But [there is a feature request](https://github.com/containers/netavark/issues/573) to be able to change firewalld zone for pods and containers.